# Resilience4j and @timeLimiter annotation for timing out and cancel Thread - CompletableFuture

Tags: java, spring-boot, resilience4j

I am having a hard time to cancel/interrupt a `CompletableFuture` task,  so it times out on the controller, but it doest stop the execution of the client even it takes more time

What I am missing? to be able to cancel my client execution on timeout

I have the next service:

```java
    @TimeLimiter(name = "ly-service-timelimiter", fallbackMethod = "fallFn")
    @Bulkhead(name = "ly-service-bulkhead", fallbackMethod = "fallFn", type = Bulkhead.Type.THREADPOOL)
    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<Void> myMethod(Request request) throws Exception {
        try {
            log.info("MyMethod Service: {}", request);
            return client.myMethod(request);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            log.info("Exception", request);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

The client

```java
    public CompletableFuture<Void> myMethod(Request request) {
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            if (future.isCancelled()) {
                log.info("MyMethod was cancelled before execution.");
                return;
            }

            try {
                log.info("Processing request", request);
                ThreadUtil.fakeRandomSleep(10000); // Simulating work

                if (future.isCancelled()) {
                    log.info("Processing was cancelled during execution.");
                } else {
                    log.info("Completed routing with TimeOut");
                    future.complete(null);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.info("completeExceptionally......");
                future.completeExceptionally(e);
            }
        });

        return future;
    }
```

The controller:

```java
    @GetMapping("/runTimeOut")
    public @ResponseBody String executeSample() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        log.info("Execute TimeOut EndPoint");
        Request request = Request.builder().build(); //Any class
        try {
            myService.myMethod(request).get();
        }catch (ExecutionException  ex){


            if(ex.getCause() instanceof java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException){
               
                log.info("TimeoutException occurred");
            }
            return "Failed";
        }

        return "OK";
    }
```

My config is:

```yaml
resilience4j:
  bulkhead:
    configs:
      default:
        max-concurrent-calls: 2
        max-wait-duration: 0ms
    instances:
      ly-service-bulkhead:
        base-config: default
  timelimiter:
    instances:
      ly-service-timelimiter:
        timeoutDuration: 900ms
        cancel-running-future: true
```

My libraries

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
...

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cancel the running task if using `CompletableFuture` provided by JDK as it is its [limitation](https://nurkiewicz.com/2015/03/completablefuture-cant-be-interrupted.html?m=1). You have to use `Future` to do it.

But `@TimeLimiter` does not support on `Future` right now. That means you cannot use the annotation approach if you want to cancel a task once it is timeout. It is also mentioned in the resilience4j Github [issue](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/905) as follows :

> You can use a TimeLimiter to decorate a method which returns a Future. A future can be canceled.
> But unfortunately Futures are not yet supported via annotations/aspects, but only via the functional style.
> We tried to implement it, but supporting Future for TimeLimiter, Retry, Bulkhead, CircuitBreaker via annotations caused us some headaches.

So the easiest way is to represent the result of the long running task using `Future` and timeout it programmatically using its decorators approach instead of the annotation approach.

So first make the client can execute a long running task which its result is returned as Future :

```java
public class Client {

    private ExecutorService executors = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    public Future<Void> myMethod() {
        return (Future<Void>) executors.submit(() -> runSomeLongRunningTask());
    }

    private void runSomeLongRunningTask() {
      // logic of the task here 

      // check if the task is cancelled here and throw exception if yes.
    }
}
```

You have to use the `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` to check if the long running task is cancelled and throw the exception if yes.

Then in the service , the equivalent decorators approach to call the client is likes :

```
public class Service  {

     private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();


     @Bulkhead(name = "ly-service-bulkhead", fallbackMethod = "fallFn", type = Bulkhead.Type.THREADPOOL)
     public Future<Void> myMethod() {

            TimeLimiterConfig config = TimeLimiterConfig.custom()
                    .cancelRunningFuture(true)
                    .timeoutDuration(Duration.ofMillis(900))
                    .build();

            TimeLimiter timeLimiter = TimeLimiter.of("ly-service-timelimiter", config);

            Callable<Void> taskDecorateWithTimeout = () -> {
                try {              
                    return timeLimiter.decorateFutureSupplier(() -> client.myMethod()).call();
                } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
                    //manually call the fallback method in case of TimeoutException
                    fallFn(ex);
                    throw ex;
                }
            };
            return executor.submit(taskDecorateWithTimeout);
     }
}
```

And the controller should not require any changes.

Answer (score 1):

Your getRequest:

```
@GetMapping("/runTimeOut")
@TimeLimiter(name = "ly-service-timelimiter", fallbackMethod = "fallFn")
public CompletableFuture<Void> String executeSample() {

    log.info("Execute TimeOut EndPoint");
    Request request = Request.builder().build(); //Any class

    return myService.myMethod(request); 
}
```

Your myMethod:

```
public CompletableFuture<Void> myMethod(Request request) {        
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {            
        log.info("Processing request", request);
        ThreadUtil.fakeRandomSleep(10000); 
    }
}
```

Should work.

Answer (score 1):

You have `ly-service-bulkhead` in annotation and `ly-bulkhead` in config.

You may also want to add `@CircuitBreaker` there.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this similar Github issue raised [here](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/905).

**Summary:**

- `@TimeLimiter`, `@Bulkhead` doesn't support `CompletableFuture` at all.
- You can't cancel a `CompletableFuture` via `@TimeLimiter`.
- You will get an `TimeoutException` from `@TimeLimiter` but `CompletableFuture` will be still running.

So, nothing is missing from your side. Just that you can't cancel a `Future` as resilience4j **annotations/aspects** doesn't support it.

Comment: Basically that is a conclusion I made earlier, but I am wondering if other people have tried it in a different way  and a missed a couple of answers that other folks made, they deleted those answers